# What is happening with file_get_contents?

Tags: php, file, file-get-contents

I have a problem with "file_get_contents ()" in PHP.

I have a PHP script that is called from JavaScript using AJAX.

In one of the entrances, when there are multiple concurrent users using it, "file_get_contents" returns an empty string, but if I access the file "data.txt" is not empty.

Does anyone know what could be happening?

I tried using "fread" and "fwrite" and even "flock" and the problem continues.

Many thanks.

```
<?php          

if(file_exists("die.txt")){die("Security");}

$file_path = "data.txt";

$ficherofile = file_get_contents($file_path);

if (($ficherofile === null || $ficherofile == "") && file_exists($file_path)){
  file_put_contents("die.txt", "a");
  die("Empty");
}

$ficherofile = $ficherofile." - Incremental text";

file_put_contents($file_path ,$ficherofile);

echo "ok";
?>
```

Comment: is your file `data.txt` in the same directory as the script?

Comment: You are missing here a not operator (!)

    if(!file_exists("die.txt")){die("Security");}

that's not the problem you are asking for...

Any concurrency here is hard to manage. Probably script is locking file, maintaining this approach flock can be a good try. Please, write a test script that can reproduct your problem. Like a foreach of jqueries ajax calls-

Comment: That's not exactly the script, but basically does the same.
The first "file_exists" is well placed, as this file is not to erase the data and I really have to check my data file "data.txt".

Comment: Yes, the files are in the same directory. This is just a test.